# Unable to build application in X-Code6-Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have created a sample project in X-Code 6.0 and Objective-C language selected.
When i'm selecting '**main.storyboard**' file, X-code crashes.
And i'm not able to build the application.
See the following error while building sample project.

[image]

Have any idea to solve this error?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: As far as I know iOS8 is still under NDA so all questions concerning it have to go to Apple Develeoper Forums

Comment: Ho..Thanks Pmk...I'll do that..

Comment: That looks very broken.  File a bug with Apple.  (And you can talk about Xcode 6/iOS 8/OSX 10.10 freely here, so carry on).

Comment: Sorry, something tells me it's not Xcode itself but maybe your copy. Otherwise you'd sure hear about it. You are talking about creating a fresh project, and having it crash on storyboard? Sounds like a local issue. Apple released Xcode 6 beta2 just days ago. Which one are you using?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about _"sample project in X-Code 6.0 and Objective-C language selected"_? A single view? Master-Detail? As far as I know, you don't select a language when creating a new project.. What is that _"sample project"_?

Comment: Xcode6 is still beta, and is highly unstable...

Comment: @pmk there is no NDA for iOS8/xcode6/OSX 10.10 so we can discuss it freely. And as a little warning when NDAs have been issued I have tried to say this before and moderators on here have just turned around and told me to back off as we aren't the NDA Police.

Comment: Thanks @bauerMusic..I was using X-Code Beta1. Issue may be with beta1.Now I'm Using Beta2.It's working fine now.